# How to detect the duplicate letters in a inputted string in python and print the letters that are duplicated in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, duplicates

How do I detect a duplicated letter in an input string?

```
FirstName = input("Enter your First Name: ")
LastName = input("Enter your Last Name: ")
FullName = FirstName + " " * 1 + LastName
```

Also I wanted to know how to display the letters that are duplicated using if-else, or other methods:
like if there are duplicated letters, it will print "The duplicate letters in your First and Last Names:" and those duplicated letters in a list and if there are no letters duplicated, it will print "There are no duplicate letters in your First and Last Names."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count the occurrences of each letter in the names, and then show those with more than one letter.

```
from collections import Counter

counts = Counter(FullName.lower())
duplicates = [c for c in counts if counts[c] > 1]
if duplicates:
    print(f'The duplicate letters in your First and Last Names: {", ".join(duplicates)}')
else:
    print('There are no duplicate letters in your First and Last Names.')
```

Note that the input is converted to lowercase so that upper and lower case letters are equivalent.

Also note that this does nothing to ignore any punctuation or whitespace that might be in the names. You could consider letters only by:

```
duplicates = [c for c in counts if counts[c] > 1 and c.isalpha()]
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for answering. How about if the list that where my duplicates that will be displayed will be in list format like [' ', ' ']?

Comment: Then just print the list variable without `join()`. I think that the formatted output is better, but if you want you could simply do: `print(f'The duplicate letters in your First and Last Names: {duplicates}'`)